# Fastlane: Invalid Signature - Invalid Info.plist error after resigning .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I have to resign an .ipa file which has been originally signed with an enterprise profile.
Due to security reasons I have no access to the repository of this project. In addition, I have to modify the build number in
.plist file.

First I use fastlane to resign the .ipa file with my distribution certificate and app store profile:

```
fastlane sigh resign /Users/myUserName/Desktop/FolderContainsMyIPA/MyIPAName.ipa --signing_identity "iPhone Distribution: MyDistributionCertName" -p /Users/myUserName/Desktop/FolderContainsMyIPA/myAppStoreProfile.mobileprovision
```

Terminal output says resigning was successful.

Then I zip and unzip the folder in order to modify the info.plist file inside of the binary payload. After zipping and uploading the .ipa to iTunes Connect, I always receive following error:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   „My App Name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Signature - Invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been
>   modified). The file at path [Template.app/Template] is not properly
>   signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution
>   certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.
>   Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the
>   target level (which override any values at the project level).
>   Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a
>   Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain
>   your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode,
>   delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release
>   target. For more information, please consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Can’t figure out what's wrong with my approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply try modifying the info.plist BEFORE resigning your .ipa file. That should work.

Comment: Thanks this was the solution.